# How to slice a long string at every specific word occurence in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split, slice

Let's say i have a long string like this :

"**at**org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:253)**at**org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:442)**at**org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:383)"

My goal is to be able to put every sentence at the "at" keyword in a variable such as :

**var1**="atorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:253)"
**var2**="atorg.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:442)"
**var3**="atorg.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:383)"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

with this code snippets you get an array of all sentences , where "at" present.

```
var str = "atorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:253)atorg.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:442)atorg.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:383)"

// It will check word from begginging to the end of the string
let result =  str.split('at').filter(elem => elem !== "");
console.log(result)
```

Now loop through this array and put every elment in a new veriable.